# How do I solve the target API level issue from Google about building my app by cn1?

Tags: codenameone

I got an important message from Google.

Update your target API level by August 31, 2023 to release updates to your app

We've detected that your app is targeting an old version of Android. To provide users with a safe and secure experience, Google Play requires all apps to meet target API level requirements.

From August 31, 2023, if your target API level is not within 1 year of the latest Android release, you won't be able to update your app.

To continue making updates to your app, ensure your app targets Android 13 (API level 33).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API level is set to API 33 by default. If you're experiencing a problem it is either because you have one of:

- A build hint explicitly setting the API back to an older version.
- A build hint that is no longer supported and triggers an API downgrade.

You can see the build hints in Codename One Settings.

Comment: I check the build hints in my app but I can't figure out the problem in it. I send my build hint on cn1 website. Would you point out how to solve the issue? Thank you.
https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_automatic_build_hint_configuration

Comment: I looked through the chat and I don't see anything wrong. I have two guesses. First: maybe the target is updated via a gradle build hint? Is there a way to tell the version of target google thinks it has? Second: the error message is misleading and it's about updating the minimum version. Probably not all the way up to 33, just not a version as old as we support.

Comment: I built my app with 
Build hint min_sdk_version = 26: 
build.gradle  minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 33
AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="33"


Build hint min_sdk_version=33:
build.gradle

minSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33

AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="33" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

Comment: Yes, but when you upload to the store is that triggering the warning. Also, check that you flushed the alpha channels correctly as [explained here](https://dev.to/codenameone/google-play-kafkaesque-experience-mp3).

Comment: I have flushed the channels before when I asked another question.
I also send the build.gradle file on the chat.

Comment: @DanielTsai looking at your chat log this somehow got resolved when you set the minimum version to a very new one. Right?  It's also obvious from the generated project that the correct target is used.

Comment: @CarlosVerdier we will need more information than that. Specific build hints. Try sending a build with include source and see if the target there is indeed 33. For Daniel the right target is set but he still gets a warning from Google which seems like a problem in the play store upload or settings.

Comment: I set build hint android.min_sdk_version = 33 and the API level becomes 33 on Google Play internal testing build. Pls. check the attached screen shot in question.
Is that OK to set android.min_sdk_version = 33 for sending production?

Comment: Ok, it's solved for me now. Yesterday I was having a warning for every apk I was uploading, but today I got a message from Google saying the issue is resolved, so I guess the warning is there until they review the app. The solution was to flush the alpha channel.

Comment: @CarlosVerdier How do you flush the alpha channel? I upload the new version to the alpha channel but the warning still exists.

Comment: @DanielTsai I just uploaded the new version to the alpha channel and promoted it to production. As you say, the warning was still there, but the next day they reviewed the app and said it was ok.

Comment: I also solved the issue after flushing the alpha channel.
Thank you.